# Why does moq not use this parameter in its setup?

Tags: c#, tdd, mocking, moq

I have this test

```
[Fact]
public void Get_if_item_is_not_in_cache_return_null_returns_true()
{
    var repo = new Repository<IProduct>(
        this.factoryMock.Object, 
        this.cacheMock.Object, 
        this.readerMock.Object, 
        this.storageMock.Object);

    var key = 1;
    const string Name = "Product1";
    var date = new DateTime(0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    var product1 = this.Product; /* returns new Product(
                                  *     "Product1", 
                                  *     new DateTime(0, DateTimeKind.Utc), 
                                  *     new Dictionary<string, decimal> 
                                  *         { { "@1lom", 0m }, { "@2lom", 0m } })     */

    this.cacheMock.Setup(
        m => m.Add(key, product1)).Returns(product1);
    this.cacheMock.Setup(
        m => m.Get<IList<IDictionary<string, object>>>(0)).Returns(null as IList<IDictionary<string, object>>);
    this.cacheMock.Setup(
        m => m.Get<IProduct>(key)).Returns(null as IProduct);
    this.factoryMock.Setup(
        m => m.Create(
            Name, 
            date, 
            this.cacheMock.Object.Get<IList<IDictionary<string, object>>>(0))).Returns(product1);

    var product2 = repo.Get(key, Name, date);

    Assert.Null(product2);
    this.cacheMock.VerifyAll();
    this.factoryMock.VerifyAll();
}
```

I get this exception

> > Moq.MockVerificationException: The following setups were not matched:
> >
> > ICache m => m.Add(1, )

The invocation contains the second parameter but why does moq not recognize it during setup? It works, when i omit the setup for .Add!?

---

**Update**
This is the code that is executed

```
public virtual T Get(int key, string productName, DateTime date)
{
    return this.Cache.Get<T>(key) ?? this.PersistenStorage.Query(productName, date) ?? this.CreateNewCacheItem(productName, date);
}

protected virtual T CreateNewCacheItem(string productName, DateTime date)
{
    var product = this.Factory.Create(productName, date, this.Cache.Get<IList<IDictionary<string, object>>>(this.RawDataKey));
    return this.Cache.Add(product.GetHashCode(), product);
}
```

Comment: You might be better off using the It.IsAny<TYPE> instead of explicit arguments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use Setup in Moq, you're saying "Return this when you see exactly these parameters". For reference types like `Product`, it will only work when it sees that exact instance. So when Get runs, it's creating a new `Product` instance internally and is not matching your expectation from `product1`.

As Chris mentioned, if you used `It.IsAny<Product>()` in the Setup instead, it would match the new instance and work as intended.

Comment: I tried this this.cacheMock.Setup(m => m.Add(key, It.IsAny<IProduct>())).Returns(product1); but i does not work

Comment: Have you tried debugging and figuring out if it's trying to call `Add` and with what parameters?

Comment: Yes, i debugged the code and it calls Add but then I saw your phrase "...when you see exactly these parameters". My Setup uses 1 as key, but the real code uses product.GetHashCode() as key. That was the problem. 

var key = product1.GetHashCode();
this.cacheMock.Setup(m => m.Add(key, It.IsAny<IProduct>())).Returns(null as IProduct);